# How can I have responsive text on my website

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I am writing a cover letter in HTML and using some jQuery plugins for the background. Sadly I can't manage its text to be responsive. Need help. I found only this https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS so far but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive text?" A code sample would help.

Comment: fonts are not shrinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want your text size to change with the size of the window, try using this css:
`font-size: 10vw;` 
This will set the size to 10% of the view width, or you can use `vh` to be relative to the view height.

You can also use a combo: `font-size:calc(10vh + 10vw);`

Comment: it helped with mobile version but as I shrink back again it became huge

Comment: Yeah, as the view width becomes bigger, so does the text. That is the definition of responsive. What you want is a media query condition to set the percentage smaller if the view is larger than a certain with, or use a fixed size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thank you Patrick I was trying to make it without media queries but it seems like the only solution and I applied that anyway